# How can I get the division of two group by on SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I've seen several posts to get the percentage of each row (using partition by), others about getting one row divided by another (using inner join with the same table), but I haven't seem this problem, so I hope this post is not a problem.

I have the following table:

```
week            group      ID
2020-01-07      A          AUR1282
2020-01-07      A          BSF9382
2020-01-07      A          EOA9284
2020-01-07      B          AIF3984
2020-01-21      A          AIG3856
2020-01-21      B          PRT3950
```

And I want to get the percentage of IDs in group A. The result should be like this:

```
group      ID_perc
A          0.66
```

This should be pretty simple. But I got this far:

```
select t1.week, count(distinct t1.ID)::float/t2.total_ID as ID_perc
from table as A
inner joint (select count(distinct ID) as total_ID 
            from table where group='B') t2
on t1.week = t2.week
where t1.group = 'A'
```

This doesn't solve my problem.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding latest change, how do you come up with 66% for all of group 'A'?

Comment: I have four occurrences for group A and two for group B. So, 4/(4+2) =0.66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this (based on your latest edit) -

```
 Select group, grp_count/total_cnt as perc
 from
 (Select group,count(*) as grp_count, min(total_cnt) as total_cnt
 from t
Cross Join (Select count(*) as total_cnt from t) t2
Group by group)
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select week, 'A' as grp,
       (count(*) filter (where group = 'A') * 1.0) / count(*)
from t
group by week;
```

Or alternatively:

```
select week, 'A' as grp,
       avg( (group = 'A')::int )
from t
group by week;
```

Comment: damn, I requested something different from what I really wanted. The percentage by week I already have (as I've posted). What I needed was the percentage for the whole table. I edited the question, but I think I shouldnt do that, right?

Comment: so sorry for that... should I edit the question again and let it the way it was? And then open another question? not sure anymore. my bad, so sorry